# How do I separate my theme's styles from editor styles?

Tags: tinymce, editor, css

Do I need to implement an editor-specific stylesheet for the WordPress WYSIWYG? In doing so will this eliminate style conflicts that I am currently experiencing?I am have not implemented an editor stylesheet so I am noticing that it is becoming very difficult to separate surrounding website styles and editor styles. What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WordPress editor shouldn't be pulling in the themes CSS files unless you have a file that is named `editor-style.css`. You can either use the editor-style.css and simply place it in your themes root directory, add certain styles to the stylesheet (not all the theme div and id tags will apply to the WordPress Editor).

Another way to do it is to use `wp_enqueue_script` to enqueue a CSS file with whatever name you wish, or in a different file location other than the themes root directory. Some authors use this method to minimize the amount of files that live in the theme root directory.

If your theme is incorrectly registering or enqueueing a script it can cause the files to be loaded into the WordPress admin area. Let me know what your theme is using for the editor stylesheet if this doesn't help so I can give you better assistance.

Comment: so basically the editor-style.css is a stylesheet dedicated and specific to the WordPress WYSIWYG? This stylesheet allows me to target styles just for the dynamic content output of the WordPress editor?

Comment: Yes, the editor-style is meant specifically for styling the WordPress Page/Post editor so it looks closer to what it does on the site. It's useful for clients and others that use the visual editor vs. HTML view.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a callback for custom TinyMCE editor stylesheet in your theme is a good (standard) way to implement an editor-specific stylesheet in WordPress. This is how it's done:

```
add_editor_style('custom-editor-style.css');
```

This function is ONLY for in-theme stylesheets, in the sense:

- The code should be added in your theme's `functions.php`
- The stylesheet file should reside right inside the theme directory i.e. for instance `.../wp-content/themes/MY-THEME/custom-editor-style.css`

**READ:** [Function Reference / add_editor_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) (WordPress Codex) and [WordPress Editor Style](http://yoast.com/wordpress-editor-style/) (Article)